# Struts2 bootstrap width of a text field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags, struts2-bootstrap-plugin

I am trying to change the width of a `<s:textfield>` I created like this:

```
<s:textfield name="process.name" key="lbl.process.name" cssClass="col-sm-4"/>
```

but it turns out into:

```
<div class="form-group ">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="ShowProcess_process_name" >
      Displayname        
   </label>    
   <div class="col-sm-9 controls">
      <input type="text" name="process.name" value="name" id="ShowProcess_process_name"class="form-control col-sm-4"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

but what I want is:

```
<div class="form-group ">
   <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="ShowProcess_process_name" >
      Displayname        
   </label>    
   <div class="col-sm-4 controls">
      <input type="text" name="process.name" value="name" id="ShowProcess_process_name"class="form-control"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to change the width via bootstrap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cssClass` is for styling input itself. To style the element which wraps input use `elementCssClass` attribute instead of `cssClass`.

```
<s:textfield name="process.name" key="lbl.process.name" elementCssClass="col-sm-4" />
```

Comment: Thanks that is what i looked for. The strange thing is that my IDE does not know this attribute...

Comment: @John Yes, it is a dynamic attribute.

Comment: Is there any way to find all dynamic attributes for tag?

Comment: @John Nope, they are dynamic. ;)

Comment: do you know why elementCssClass does not work for jquerey <j:autocompleter> ?

Comment: @John Because it is struts2-bootstrap-plugin attribute.

Comment: do you know how to fix this problem for the autocompleter ?